# CPanel/VPS - Search all messages for URL

Tags: search, cpanel, vps

I need a command that will search through the body text of all emails (sent/received/junk) for all email accounts on a VPS server for a particular URL (which may be embedded in text). Possibly a grep command?

Apologies if this is obvious!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple and basic grep command:

```
grep -ri 'particular url' /home/*/mail/*
```

-i (ignore case so no case sensitive search)
-r recursive; searches through all the files/folders

Give it a try!